# Custom Attributes - Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-orientation

I am currently having a very specific challenge.
Here is the thing:

I built a custom view, where i want to set a specific attribute from xml layout.
I obtain my custom attributes in the constructor for the view. 
Now after a *orientation change* this constructor is **not called again**, but i set different values for my custom attributes.
is there any way to **automatically** obtain these new values, or do i have to set them manually on orientation change (or inflate again)?

Custom View:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.MyCustomView,
        0, 0);

   try {
       mAttr = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyCustomView_customAttr, false);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
}
```

layout-landscape

```
<com.me.MyCustomView
     custom:customAttr="false" />
```

layout-portrait

```
<com.me.MyCustomView
     custom:customAttr="true" />
```

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using  `android:configChanges="orientation"`  on your **Activity** in manifest ?

like this :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

If you do, you are requesting for managing the orientation change by yourself, so you are responsible for recreating the view as needed (re-inflate it, yes). You can do it in the `onConfigurationChanged()` call in your **Activity**.

But if you remove this setting, the Activity should be recreated by default so, your layout would be build again with the new attributes...

As explain in this Topic : [oncreate called on every re-orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618703/activity-lifecycle-oncreate-called-on-every-re-orientation)

More informations about [Handling Runtime changes here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

Comment: thanks very much!!! that worked out! i thought there might be a way around re-creating the view, or manually setting the attributes... but it seems there isn't.